# Can a low amps 48v battery handle big DC motor

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, dc-motor, battery-operated, electrical

I have a 48V DC motor, 3500W at 300A, combined with a dc controller with 60A constant and 120A peak discharge rate.

Can a 48v li-ion battery with 20A constant and 40A peak discharge rate, safely drive the dc motor?

Will the battery be damaged by a dc motor that will draw more current than the battery can give, or will the dc motor run at a reduced (proportional) power/torque, given by the battery's capabilities and the battery remain intact and safe?

The DC controller has current limiter protection at 120A fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3500W @ 200A is only 12V not 48V and DC motors tend to draw 10x typ the power on full voltage surge start unless using a suitable PWM controller.

Or if you consider 3500W @ 48W that implies a load of 3500/48= 73 A.

Either way you need to show datasheets for everything, or ask with better data.

Conclusion. : Not a good match

update

---

I found your specs.

It is a 3 HP 48V motor (11.8HP pk) that draws 3500W (your spec) at peak efficiency  (PE) at  6000/6400 RPM or a drop of 6.26% from a no load top speed that draws 4A.

This ratio of PE to no load = 73A/4A = 18.25 implies how much slower you need to ramp up the speed to prevent blowing your slo-blow battery fuse or PTC matched to the battery C rating and your specified need for 20A or about 1/4 of the 3HP current of 73A.

The controller can handle it only if you manually reduce the ramp rate of voltage rise significantly and use a meter to gauge it.
A battery pack may exist for this rating but that is a lot of current.

[[Specs]](https://www.robotmarketplace.com/products/0-a28-400-f48.html)

```
Diameter    3.0 in.
Length  7.8 in.
Peak Horsepower     11.5
Peak Torque     7260 oz-in
RPM at 48V  6400 rpm
Shaft Diameter  1/2 in.
Shaft Length    2 in.
Keyway  1/8 in.
Capacitors  Yes
Magnet Type     Neodymium
No Load Amps    4.4 Amps
Terminal Resistance     0.066 Ohms
Kt  10.05 oz-in/Amp
Kv  135 rpm/Volt
Peak Effieciency (PE)   85%
RPM at PE   6000
Torque at PE (oz-in)    510
Horsepower at PE    3.0 HP
Current at PE   55A
HP Range for 75%+ Efficiency    1.0 to 8.1
Weight  7.3 lbs.

0-A28-400-F48
```

Comment: Sorry for incomplete information. This is all the data I have about the dc engine. Green in color, A28 400 48V with fan. My concern is not the volts, but the amps the engine could possibly pull from a battery that can't supply it? Or, will the battery determine the engine power in proportion to its capabilities and remain intact?

Comment: I have picture with datasheet upload error...

Comment: A better approach (aside from choosing a motor matched to the battery capabilities) would be a PWM driver that can limit the current it draws from the source.  Then the motor will get as much as it can without overloading the battery.  Whether such a driver exists off the shelf, or needs to be designed, is another question.

Comment: @TimWescott That's what I was assuming for the controller was PWM slow rise in ramp voltage.   Actually a better solution is an LED  PWM reactive Constant Current power supply for a fixed mechanical load.

Answer (score 2):

The only way that a battery will limit the current of a DC motor is by the voltage drop across the natural internal resistance of the battery subtracting substantially from the battery terminal voltage. If that voltage drop is significant and sustained, the battery will get hot quite quickly. Letting the battery and interconnecting wiring limit the current may be ok if the excess current only lasts a second or so during starting. If it lasts longer than that, the battery will probably be damaged.

The situation described seems to indicate no chance of success.